# how to find out the Height dynamically in highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

for your reference jsfiddle.net/dbDRG/10 how to find out the Height dynamically(blue and red ) color Lines . Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get "d" paramter form path, and compare start/end point (y value).